# How can I have a shell for git like in Windows?

Tags: command-line, git

When I use Windows, the shell (even a standard Windows shell) shows basic information about the git repository when you are in a git repository.  Things like the active branch and maybe some color coding.

Is there a way to have the same in Ubuntu?

Comment: what version of git do you have installed in windows? 
What commands do you run to get this information? 
Have you tried those commands with the `git-core` package installed?

Comment: On git i have the latest version, but simply if i use the command line and i'm inside a git repository, i see the name of the active branch

Answer (score 4):

The Windows Git shell, which is really just bash, sets the prompt `$PS1` to a long string that includes `$(__git_ps1)`.

`__git_ps1` is defined as a function, nearly 100 lines long, that prints the name of the current branch in parentheses.

`/etc/profile` (which is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\profile`, at least on my system)) invokes `/etc/git-completion.bash`, which defines the `__git_ps1` function, sets `$PS1`, defines some git-specific completions, among other things.

The `git-completion.bash` used by Git Bash appears to be based on [this](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion).

Comment: So exactly what i should do to activate this on uBuntu? :) Sorry but i'm new.

Comment: Go to the Home directory and type the command in terminal as "gedit .baschr" and you will prompt to edit the .baschr file.But make sure to have a original copy in a different directory for safety.

Answer (score 4):

For color:

```
git config --global color.ui true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use zsh as your shell, you might find [my config files](https://github.com/patrick-conley/zsh-config) useful. Try `source prompt/blocky` to see what the prompt looks like in a Git repository.

Answer (score 1):

- [How to stop bash prompt colours from escaping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163347/how-to-stop-bash-prompt-colours-from-escaping) has an example. You could copy it from the answer and then use gedit to paste it to the bottom of your the .bashrc file in your home directory (making a backup, first, of course).
- If the .bashrc file Keith mentions in his answer is part of git it will be licensed with GPL2 so you should be free to past it into your .bashrc file as well. You'll have to grab the /etc/git-completion.bash file and install it somewhere too, and have your new .bashrc reference it.
- Here's something else you could paste and try from Arturo Fernandez at http://www.bsnux.com/recipes/how-display-you-current-git-branch-prompt.html

```
 # Displaying git branch inside prompt
 function parse_git_branch {
   git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
 }

 function proml {
   local       GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
   local       WHITE="\[\033[0;37m\]"

 PS1="[\u@\h \w$GREEN\$(parse_git_branch)]$WHITE\$ "
 PS2='> '
 PS4='+ '
}
proml
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add windows-like git-bash to Ubuntu terminal:

1. Add to the end of `~/.bashrc`:
   `` PS1='\[\033]0;$MSYSTEM:${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$ ' ``
2. execute in terminal:
   `source ~/.bashrc`